# Case Insensitive spell checker in R

Tags: r, spell-checking, hunspell

I am currently using hunspell_check() function in hunspell package in R to classify words as correct or incorrect. But the dictionary it uses is case sensitive.

Is there a way to specify case insensitivity if I have to continue using the same package? Or is there any other package in R which I can use?

Answer (score 3):

Based on [this issue](https://github.com/ropensci/hunspell/issues/22), it looks like using `toupper` is a workaround.  E.g.:

```
g <- c("albany", "Albany", "ALBANY")

hunspell_check(g)
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE

hunspell_check(toupper(g))
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks. Will check it.